# How to detect, when a windows form from external process is loaded

Tags: windows, winforms, process

In project A, I am starting an exe (build from project B) with some arguments. Depending on the arguments, different form is loaded. In project A, I need to capture the moment, when the form, started by the exe (build from project B) is started. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the moment"?  Are you saying you want to have something like an event handler that will do something synchronously at the moment the form is loaded?  Or do you just want to note that it's loaded at all?

Comment: You working in C# or VB.Net?

Comment: Yes, I need something as event to capture the moment the form is shown. C# and VB both work. T.S. can you be more specific which Api to use, and do you suggest I execute it in an infinite loop until such process or window is found, as this might hang my app forever.

Comment: If Project A is in VB.Net, then you can set its "Make single instance application" option in Project --> Properties.  Now, over in Project B, you simply run the Project A Executable again with a string parameter to indicate which Form was started.  Since Project  A is single instance, **the already running instance** will get a [My.Application.StartupNextInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9z4eyh8(v=vs.90).aspx) event notification where you can retrieve the passed string and do something with it.

Comment: T.S. - the process starts, however, the form is being shown a bit later, as it takes some time to load. This time is different for each form, so capturing when the process is started will not work. On the other hand, the FindWindowEx will return a handle to the window, but this will also not work for me, as I mentioned, the loading takes some time, hence, I will be notified earlier than needed.

@Idle_Mind the projects are in C#.I found this solution, which I will try soon: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12890/Single-Instance-C-Application-for-NET